# Sampling analog signal at 100 kHz with raspberry pi

Tags: microcontroller, adc, uart, buffer, sample-and-hold

I want to sample a ultrasonic wave at 100 ksps.

Currently I am using a Raspberry Pi and an external ADC communicating with each other via I2S at 96 kHz.

Since the Raspberry Pi cannot support higher speed data transfer through conventional serial protocols I want to add a microcontroller in between the Raspberry Pi and ADC which can sample the signal at 100 ksps and send the digitized signal to Raspberry Pi via UART protocol.

Is it possible to send 100 k samples of 16-bit data over UART in a second to a Raspberry Pi and also any recommendations for the microcontrollers would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about this for a second: serial in, serial out at the same rate? Are you sure you can't use a higher frequency on the Pi, or maybe SPI?

Comment: Do you need to sample in real time, or can you sample into a buffer, and then send the buffer up at a more reasonable speed?

Comment: @ScottSeidman, I don't need to sample in real time,  I just need to get 10 seconds worth of data and analyze later. Can you suggest me some buffers that could do this? Really appreciate your help, Sir.

Comment: what about if you use 2 or more raspberry pi to sample. Maybe 2 or 3 are enough to sample at higher rates

Comment: 100k x 2bytes is at least 1.6 Mbps sync is not toohard using 3MHz SPI then   using 3Mbps UART